# CloudKit Dashboard logs history and live EMPTY

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Whenever I enter the CloudKit and check the logs in the development database I can see NO EVENTS at all. Neither in history or live events.

Although I can see on telemetrics that records have been created, modified, deleted and even some conflicts have occurred.

Do I have to enable something actively to send logs? or they should be showing up by default?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Same here, also in the production database.